# Data submit using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am submitting data using jQuery/AJAX in JSON format but the success function is not being hit.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function addOrder(accounts,profiles) {
    var ticker = $('#ticker').val();
    var Quatity = parseFloat($('#quantity').val()); 
    var lmtPrice = parseInt($('#price').val());
    var OrderType = $('#type').val();
    var Action = $('#action').val();
    var TIF = $('#tif').val();
    var url = rootURL+'/submit?account='+ accounts+'&profile='+ profiles+'&Ticker='+ ticker+'&Quatity='+ Quatity+'&lmtPrice='+ lmtPrice+'&OrderType='+ OrderType+'&Action='+ Action+'&TIF='+ TIF;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('orderform').serialize(),
        /*data: dataString,*/
        complete : function(){
            alert(this.url)
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert('Order created successfully');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Order error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    addOrder(option,option2);
});
```

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="orderform">
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">Ticker:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="ticker" id="ticker" /></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">Quatity:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" /></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">lmtPrice:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="price" id="price" /></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">OrderType:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <select name="type" id="type">
            <option>MKT</option>
            <option>LMT</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">Action:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <select name="action" id="action">
            <option>BUY</option>
            <option>SELL</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">TIF:</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <select name="tif" id="tif">
            <option>DAY</option>
            <option>GTC</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix box">
      <div class="col-md-4 righttext label">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="submit" />
         <!--<button id="btnSave">submit</button>-->
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The script always hits the error function when I hit the submit button.

Comment: are u sure you are sending it to the correct url? what does the response say in the error block?

Comment: Yes url is correct with some parameters. response says just Order Error : error. No any error in console.

Comment: `selector` in `data` attribute of `ajax` is not right. it should be a `id` selector `$('#orderform')`.

Comment: Can you post your code that returns back the JSON after you process the form?

Comment: RonyLoud i have update selector but no luck.

Comment: Yes John it return JSON.

Comment: do you set the HTTP status code of 200 along with your response?

Comment: contentType I think is wrong also - remove that completely.

Comment: ContentType is json.

Comment: How to set status code?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Thanks man. Its resolved by removing ContentType.

Comment: But its working with TYpe : 'GET'. with POST given ERROR
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
WHY?

Comment: Language JQUERY Ajax.

Comment: I mean backend language to process the form. whatever language is behind the '/submit' URL. I've assumed PHP in my answer.

Comment: Yes API in php.

Comment: Are you using IIS? If so which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be because of this. Not sure if this is a typo

```
data: $('orderform').serialize()
```

Here you need to add the selector, that is id

```
data: $('#orderform').serialize()
```

Since you are using a button type submit prevent the default behaviour before executing the ajax

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        addOrder(option,option2);

});
```

or use `button type='button'` instead of `submit`

Comment: Update but No luck.

Comment: When i add preventDefault() it given error in consol
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ok there it mean it s working now, and making the ajax call. You can check the network tab and verify the ajax call. It may be you are trying to load sometime without running the application in server. Also why do youe need to pass the paramaters in url when you are already passing it in ajax data

Comment: Its working Fine with Type:'GET'. Only Given Error When type:POST.

Comment: In NetWork tab given Error 405 Method not allowed.

Comment: check your server side code. This solution address your question in the thread

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove contentType as you are not passing JSON.

You also need to ensure you are setting a HTTP status code of 200 to land in the success function from your JSON response. If you are using PHP for example:

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo json_encode($yourReturnArray);
```

You are also sending both a URL of key value pairs AND serializing the form data sent in data: You only need to do one or the other. Remove the line

```
data: $('#orderform').serialize()
```

as you are sending that data in your URL.

You could also do with adding some better error catching:

```
$.ajax({
    url     : YOUR_URL,
    success : function(data, status, xhr) {
        //
    },
    error   : function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        ajaxError(jqXHR, status, error);
    }
});

function ajaxError(jqXHR, status, error) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connected.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500]. ' + jqXHR.responseText;
    } else if (error === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (error === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (error === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    alert(msg);
}
```